# Should GSON ignore varying types if they're not used in a class?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm making an API call that returns JSON which has a particular field which either returns `false` or a map depending on content. It's a field that I don't care about. I expected GSON to ignore this particular field, though it doesn't seem to be. The object generation fails with the following message:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 403560
```

I've seen this particular question ([Gson deserialize json with varying value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992891/gson-deserialize-json-with-varying-value-types)). I want to make sure I need to make a custom deserializer before doing so. I'm wondering if I may have another issue.

**edit:**

Example:

```
"anonymous_flag": {  }

vs

"anonymous_flag": "yes"
```

**Another Edit:**

I actually had the field in my model object... I was referencing the wrong class. Judge away :)

Comment: Please can you share your JSON string to make it more clear? I have already answered it in the same context. Read it [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125695/how-to-convert-json-string-to-a-java-object-when-the-structure-is-different?answertab=votes#tab-top). It might help you. If you need more clarity then please let me know.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I actually did include that field in my model object, which was the problem. I'll keep the question around as a reminder to others to double check their code :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are deserializing the JSON into a domain object of your own design, you can simply omit the field from it if you're not interested in the value. GSON will ignore the field in the JSON.

Comment: I'm *not* including the field that seems to be giving me trouble. Do you know for sure that GSON should completely ignore it if so? Maybe I have another issue.

Comment: I tested it before posting and didn't get an error. Which version of GSON are you using?

Comment: Same here. I can't explain that.

Comment: Hm... must be something else going on.

Comment: *headdesk* Yeah, I did have the field included in my model. I was looking at the wrong class.