# Parse Json values using GSON that can be double or Strings

Tags: java, android, json, gson, deserialization

I am trying to parse JSON using GSON library, but I am having some issues.

The problem is that some of the keys can contain double and String values. 
Here is an example:

```
"message":"unlimited"
```

But this can also be:

```
"message":4.0
```

Can anyone help me to find a solution for this?

Comment: Did you try and specific code? If so, what's the more specific problem, such as an exception on the non-string?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992891/gson-deserialize-json-with-varying-value-types

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom type for your `message` field, and implement a [TypeAdapter](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) for it.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Darko, there is a great example at the link I've attached, do you want me to actually code the solution for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Object aObj = jObj.get("message");

            if (aObj instanceof Double) {
               Log.d("Oobjext",":" + aObj);

            }else if(aObj instanceof String){
                Log.d("Oobjext string",":" + aObj);
            }
```

Most of the times, server should not be doing this. Because checking the type of "key" will be a hectic task.